# SLES can't upgrade packages via zypper or yast2

Tags: proxy, ssl, sles

I am getting errors whenever this box tries to phone to grab a package.

via yast:

`There was an error in the repository initialization.

Download (curl) error for

https://nu.novell.com/repo/repoindex.xml?cookies=0&redentials=NCCcredentials':

Error code: Unrecognized error

Error message: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA
cert is OK. Details:

error:14090086:SSL`

via zypper:

`Check if the URI is valid and accessible.
Download (curl) error for 'https://nu.novell.com/repo/$RCE/SLES11-SP3-Pool/sle-11-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml?credentials=NCCcredentials':
Error code: Unrecognized error
Error message: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

Any ideas? I know this box is sitting behind a proxy, but I can hit this website via firefox and the proxy is set up correctly because I can hit other sites outside of my network.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that it was a corrupt SLES registration. heres the link that helped me.

https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3303599